# Change the size of splash image in a Trusted Web Activity

Tags: android, android-studio, google-chrome, trusted-web-activity

I have created a Trusted Web activity and added a splash image to it in android studio. I have followed [this](https://limhenry.medium.com/adding-splash-screen-to-trusted-web-activity-e9ff95c7c4bd) link to do it. After a lot of googling, I was able to do it. Now I want to resize the splash image. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the image that is part of the splash screen larger, you will need to add a larger version of that image to the project's source code.

From the article linked, the images should be somewhere like `res/drawable/ic_splash.png`. Replacing this image with a larger version should result in a larger image in the splash screen.

Additionally, you will want to look into [Android screen densities](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities). Those are alternate images you can provide for screens that have higher resolution and are preferred by Android over the one in the `drawable` folder.

As an example, let's say you want the image to be 512px by 512px at the baseline `mdpi`. You would need:

| DPI | Path | Multiplier | Image Size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ldpi | /res/drawable-ldpi/ | 0.75 | 384x384px |
| mdpi (baseline) | /res/drawable/ | 1.0 | 512x512px |
| hdpi | /res/drawable-hdpi/ | 1.5 | 768x768px |
| xhdpi | /res/drawable-xhdpi/ | 2.0 | 1024x1024px |
| xxhdpi | /res/drawable-xxhdpi/ | 3.0 | 1536x1536px |
| xxxhdpi | /res/drawable-xxxhdpi/ | 3.0 | 2048x2048px |